# how to call a jsp which is in a different WAR file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf

I have a click here link on a jsp. On clicking, another jsp which is in another WAR file has to be called.  I'm using JSF frmework.

Can anyone help me out please....!!!

Answer (score 2):

How about just anchor tag ?

```
<a href="http://someserver:port/app2/some.jsp">Click Me </a>
```

JSF

```
 <h:outputLink value="http://someserver:port/app2/some.jsp"><h:outputText value="Click Me"/></h:outputLink>
```

Comment: added JSF tags too. but you can always use simple HTML tag in jsf too. It will not have to convert to basic HTML then

Comment: Thank u!!! but do i really need to specify the server and port number even if both the WAR files are deployed in same location ?

Comment: Try with just  `/app2/some.jsp` , where app2 is context root of second app

Comment: I have tried with this<h:outputLink value="/app2/index.jsp"><h:outputText value="here"></h:outputText></h:outputLink>

Comment: I have tried with this 
<h:outputLink value="/app2/index.jsp"><h:outputText value="here"></h:outputText></h:outLink>
but it's not working